# RTF string with image from WPF RichTextBox won't display in WinForms RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

The RTF string below contains an image and was created from a WPF RichTextBox. When I set the RTF string below to a WinForms RichTextBox.Rtf property the image is not displayed. How can I get the image to show in the WinForms RichTextBox?

Here is the code to create the RTF string from the WPF RichTextBox:

```cs
  private static string ExportRtf(RichTextBox richTextBox)
  {
     var document = richTextBox.Document;
     var r = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
        r.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        return encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
     }
  }
```

Here is the WPF RichTextBox display:

[image]

Here is the WinForms RichTextBox display:

[image]

Here is the RTF string:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Calibri;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs21\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch help}{\ltrch {\*\shppict{\pict\picwgoal435\pichgoal300\pngblip
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}}}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
}
}
```

Comment: Try to insert a PNG image in a WinForms' RichTextBox. You'll probably have more luck pasting from the Clipboard. When you do, see the format that is actually pasted in. You'll probably see `\wmetafile8`. Without embedding the image in a metafile (WMF), the bitmap is probably just ignored.